# How to trigger code when a thread exits, without using functions *_at_thread_exit?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Let's say I have two threads in my application, and I need my main thread to be notified when the other one exits.

I am aware that C++11 provides `std::notify_all_at_thread_exit()`, or `std::promise::set_{value,exception}_at_thread_exit()`, and that's exactly what I am looking for, however the version of the STL I use (4.7.2) does not implement these functions yet (see points 30.5 and 30.6.5 on [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)).

Is there any chance I can mimic that? Thanks,

Comment: What is your main thread doing currently while it waits for the other thread to exit?

Comment: @Troy My main thread is performing some computation; it is not idle.

Comment: You could wrap the functions that you execute in those threads in functions that will notify the main thread through whatever means you prefer.

Comment: @sbi Where I am lost is what means can I use to do that? For example, how could I raise an exception in the main thread when the other thread exits?

Comment: I don't know whether and how you can throw exceptions across threads in C++. (I have access only to C++98 and some things from C++11.) However, you could certainly raise a thread-safe (either atomic or mutex-protected) flag and check for that in the main thread.

Comment: Can your main thread just try_join at an interval? Presumably your other thread is not detached?

Comment: A 0 second try_join shouldn't? Should just poll no?

Comment: Doesn't `std::notify_all_at_thread_exit()` work through the main thread waiting on a condition variable anyway?

Comment: what about llvm's std C++ library?

Comment: @Walter I cannot change the STL version just like that; I have to deal with what I currently have!

Comment: @piwi Did you take a look at boost ? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html

Comment: @sbi Checking regularly whether the thread is running is pretty intrusive in my case, but I'll prospect whether I could do that, using an atomic value as sbi suggested

Comment: @log0 I still have to join the thread to check whether an exception was raised

Comment: @sbi Any idea if using Boost.Signal would be feasible?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Boost, there is [boost::notify_all_at_thread_exit()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.notify_all_at_thread_exit) in Boost.Thread.

This could also be done using a *thread-local variable*, which registers a callback at the destructor. This is actually how the function is implemented in libc++. Unfortunately gcc 4.7 doesn't support the `thread_local` storage class yet, so this cannot work.

But if we are allowed to use POSIX thread functions, then we could associate a destructor to a TLS with `pthread_key_create`, which allowed us to simulate the function as:

```
void notify_all_at_thread_exit(std::condition_variable& cv,
                               std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock) {
    using Arg = std::tuple<pthread_key_t, 
                           std::condition_variable*, 
                           std::unique_lock<std::mutex>>;

    pthread_key_t key;
    pthread_key_create(&key, [](void* value) {
        std::unique_ptr<Arg> arg (static_cast<Arg*>(value));
        std::get<2>(*arg).unlock();
        std::get<1>(*arg)->notify_all();
        pthread_key_delete(std::get<0>(*arg));
    });

    pthread_setspecific(key, new Arg(key, &cv, std::move(lock)));
}
```

(This is optimized for one variable only. You may change this to register a stack of condition variables.)